# File upload : who is responsible for setting HTTP headers

Tags: http, file-upload, http-headers

I'm trying to understand how HTTP file uploads work.

For instance, my VueJS app is calling a REST API (with Axios). When calling `axios.request`, no headers are set. There is just a `FormData` object containing the file to upload.

When the request arrives to the backend, I see that a `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; ...` header has been added to the request.

At which moment is this header created? Who is responsible for creating the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a file upload Ajax request, in Axios, it's the browser that set the `Content-Type: multipart/form-data;...` header.

In Axios source code [lib/adapters/xhr.js](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/adapters/xhr.js) (the one that take charge of XMLHttpRequest), the HTTP request data will be checked. If it is an instance of `FormData`, then `Content-Type` header would be deleted and let browser do the job.

In [lib/adapters/xhr.js](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/adapters/xhr.js) (look at the comment in the source code):

```
if (utils.isFormData(requestData)) {
  delete requestHeaders['Content-Type']; // Let the browser set it
}
```

For `utils.isFormData()`, the logic is:

```
// code in lib/utils.js
function isFormData(val) {
  return (typeof FormData !== 'undefined') && (val instanceof FormData);
}
```